Sketch the graph of the equation $⌊x⌋^2 +⌊y⌋^2 =4$.
So,I have solved this question with pen and paper. and it gave me the following graph (I hope  the picture or maybe the link of the picture of the graph is uploaded) Here is the graph I made
But the thing is when I tried plotting it on Desmos, the graph is the exact opposite i.e., if you can see the image I have uploaded, then you will see that the shaded parts have only one side bordered by a solid line and the rest of the sides are having dotted line as borders. But in desmos it is showing that the dotted lines on my graph are actually the solid lines in desmos graph and my bordered line is the dotted line in desmos... (for reference I'll provide the link/picture of the graph provided by desmos...)
Here is the graph provided by desmos

Your graph is incorrect. The square with $\lfloor x\rfloor =2$ should be one unit to the right.

Desmos doesn't have a brain. Always keep this in mind when using mathematical software.

@jjagmath it's gif function we are talking about... So obviously 2 will not be included in the graph plotting

In your graph there is a square with vertices $(1,0)$, $(2,0)$, $(2,1)$, $(1,1)$. That square shouldn't be there, it's not part of the graph.

@jjagmath , how so???

@jjagmath isn't it the definition of gif or box function???

Take, for example, the center of the square: $(1.5, 0.5)$. For this point we have $\lfloor x\rfloor^2+\lfloor y\rfloor^2 =  \lfloor 1.5\rfloor^2+\lfloor 0.5\rfloor^2 = 1^2+0^2 =1 \ne 4$

Can you like represent it pictorially ... My brain is not understanding simple English

https://ibb.co/FWPKJv1

Do you see it now?

@AbhisiktaRay Note that 2D graphing software are almost always inaccurate when you restrict them to lower dimensional outputs (the edge of your boxes, for example). Here, $x=2$ is a possible solution, but Desmos misses it. Wolfram gives the correct graph, but not always.

Desmos is OK for most explicit relations, and 2D-region solutions, but not more than that. Boundary regions should always be handled manually.

Your graph is not correct. The rightmost square is at the wrong position. For any $(x,y)$ in that square, $\lfloor x\rfloor^2+\lfloor y\rfloor^2=1^2+0^2\neq 4$.

In response to your situation about plotting in Desmos. I've tried plotting it, not sure if you noticed something (see below), Desmos can be inaccurate if the function is complicated.

Here is the result from Wolframalpha

The graph is not correct.

Thanks, I've improve my answer

So is my graph correct? I admit I made a calculation mistake.. but consider my graph to be a rough sketch... So is it correct? Like the plotting (ignore the values)

If I ignore the numbers, then your graph looks correct. But Note numbers on x and y axis are necessary

@math... Yeah, but the graph you shared says a different story , it shows that all the numbers that are lying at the border of the squares are included... Whereas the eqn says that only border of number is included in the square .... Any idea why so???

@AbhisiktaRay do you for example the line $x=3,0\leq y\leq1$ should not exists? If that is the case, then it may be Wolframalpha's error, you can look at the bottom of the page.

COMMENT.- Confirmation that you are right, is given by Desmos itself by plotting
$⌊x⌋^2+⌊y⌋^2\le4$ instead of $⌊x⌋^2+⌊y⌋^2=4$. In several cases, for example, with isolated points,  Desmos does not graph correctly which you can verify with the  point $(2,0)$ in the curve $y^2=(x-2)^2(x-3)$.


Your right square $[1,2)\times[0,1)$ is wrong. It is not included in the solution set. Its corner $(1,0)$ does not satisfy the equation. It must have been $$[2,3)\times[0,1)$$
instead. You have to shift it one unit to the right.
Other three squares which are in the solution set are
$$[-2,-1)\times[0,1)$$
$$[0,1)\times[2,3)$$
$$[0,1)\times[-2,-1)$$

Yeah, I made a mistake there.. but is it correct ignoring my mistake?

@AbhisiktaRay Your other three squares are ok. Borders of squares in Desmos output are wrong. That is what I can roughly see from your uploads.

Thanks for letting me know
